# Recoverable Fatal Error - Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, get-posts, date-time

Im using ACF and trying to show a post type title based on the current time. So I have my post type entry with start_time and end_time and my conditional is showing my div.onAir, but Im getting this Recoverable Fatal Error. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $time_now = date("g:i a");
    $shows = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'shows',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'start_time',
          'compare' => '<=',
          'value' => $time_now,
          'type' => 'DATETIME',
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'end_time',
          'compare' => '<=',
          'value' => $time_now,
          'type' => 'DATETIME',
        )
      ),
    ));
  if( $shows ) {
    foreach( $shows as $show ){ ?>
       <div class="onAir">
         Currently On Air: <?php echo the_title($show); ?>
       </div>
  <?php
  wp_reset_query();
}
} ?>
```

I feel Im close, but I haven't seen this particular error before. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Tom changed my code up to use WP_Query. I had an issue with the timestamps in ACF and WP matching up. Once I figured that out, this code renders the correct comparison of show posts that I was going for. Please note that I used `date_i18n('g:i a');` which fixed my localization timestamp. Thanks Tom and Yuri!

```
<?php

$time = date_i18n('g:i a');
$shows = get_field('station_shows', false, false);
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'       => 'shows',
  'posts_per_page'  => 1,
  'post__in'            => $shows,
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
          'key'     => 'start_time',
          'compare' => '<=',
          'value'   =>  date_i18n('g:i a', $time),
          'type'    => 'TIME',
      ),
      array(
          'key'     => 'end_time',
          'compare' => '>=',
          'value'   => date_i18n('g:i a', $time),
          'type'    => 'TIME',
      )
  ),
 ) );
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) { while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
 $query-   >the_post();

 echo '<div class="onAir"><h3>Currently On Air @ ';
 the_title();
 if (get_field('dj', $query->ID)) {
           $dj = get_field('dj');
           echo ' w/ ';
        echo $dj;
    }
     echo '</h3></div>';
    } wp_reset_postdata();
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Note that you should set `suppress_filters` to false when using `get_posts` to avoid the performance hit, otherwise using `WP_Query` is always better. Also, `wp_reset_query` shouldn't be used here, it's for cleanup after `query_posts`

Comment: Thanks Tom, yes I changed it to new WP_Query and the error changed to Object of class WP_Tax_Query

Comment: It sounds like you kept the `foreach` the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title` doesn't work that way:

```php
the_title( $before, $after, $echo );
```

`$before` is the text that comes before the title, but you didn't give it a string/text, you gave it a post object. Post objects aren't strings, PHP doesn't know what to do so it stops and prints an error instead.

For `the_title` to work, you need to setup the current postdata. Normally a standard loop does this by calling `the_post` on the query, but you've chosen to use `get_posts` instead.

This is what a standard post `WP_Query` post loop should look like:

```php
$query = new WP_Query([ ... ]);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        //.... display post here
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling WordPress functions incorrectly. I fixed, try this code.

```
<?php
    $time_now = date( "g:i a" );
    $shows    = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'  => 'shows',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'start_time',
                'compare' => '<=',
                'value'   => $time_now,
                'type'    => 'DATETIME',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'end_time',
                'compare' => '<=',
                'value'   => $time_now,
                'type'    => 'DATETIME',
            )
        ),
    ) );

    if ( $shows ) :
        foreach ( $shows as $show ) :
    ?>

    <div class="onAir">
        Currently On Air: <?php echo get_the_title($show->ID); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Okay that took away the error, but now is showing the title of the parent page which template has the time query in....Im trying to get the "shows" title to show where the_title() is

Comment: Yes, my mistake, updated the code.

Comment: Can you explain in your question what you did? If this is just a copy paste solution then it doesn't really answer the question or explain/teach anything, the question hasn't really been answered

Comment: I changed the title output code to make it work correctly.

Comment: Well the question of the error has be fixed, but the output still isn't accurate. I am now populating an on air show (post type), but its the wrong show for the time frame....so Im still off somewhere. Thanks for you help Tom and Yuri